# Bash Script read hostnames from .txt file and place in variable for ssh

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ssh

I created a Bash Script that is the following:

```
File=/library/logs/file.txt
ssh -n username@<ip> "$(< testscript.sh)" > $File
```

It will remote into a machine and run a script and place the output in file.txt
What I need to do now is instead of manually entering an ip address, I need to have it read from a list of hostnames coming from a .txt file and have it place it in a variable that will substitute the ip address. An example would be: ssh username@Variable in which "Variable" will be changing each time a word is read from a file containing hostnames. Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xargs with -I

```
cat hosts.txt | xargs -I %REPL ssh user@%REPL
```

-I defines a "replacement-string", in this case "%REPL" (but you can set it to what you like). 
Then that specific string will be will be replaced in the command, with each line from input.

Another way i like, is using printf

```
echo -e "host1.com\nhost2.com" | xargs -n1 printf "ssh user@%s -p 999\n"
```

This is especially great, if you wanted to use more lines in the same command.. Imagine that you have a file with username on line 1 and hostname on line 2. You could simply do:

```
xargs -n2 printf "ssh %s@%s -p 999\n" < user_and_host.txt
```

---

**Passwords**

All this, assumes you are using SSH keys because, *by design*, the openssh client will not let you "script" passwords.

If you want to script using password authentication, there are tons of hints and methods (someone will yell "expect" any second now). But i did them all at some point or another, and they bring **eternal pain and indigestion**.

Its **not worth it**, scripting this yourself. Have a look at my favorite tool for this:

- [SSH Power tool](https://code.google.com/p/sshpt/)

This will let you pretty much do what you need. Give it username, password, one or more commands to run + a bunch of hosts/ip's. When its done, you'll have a nice CSV-file with the result of every command, ordered by its host.

Comment: Or simply `xargs -I %REPL ssh user@%REPL < hosts.txt`

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, now how would I go about having the password automatically entered for me instead of having to enter a password to ssh in every time? Is there a way for when it prompts "Password:" to have my password automatically entered?

Comment: Also is there a way to have it skip a hostname if it isn't connected to the network? It looks like it give me this error "port 22: Operation timed out" and then cancels running all other hostnames

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem, if there are multiple hosts in the hosts.txt file. lines from 2nd host onwards will be provided as input to ssh command. I would suggest `for host in $(< host.txt); do ssh@$host ... ; done` OR create a separate file descriptor for `host.txt` file & read from that.

Comment: @Technic1an Ahh.. The "scripted ssh-password" question. This is a very old one indeed and im sure many duplicates can be found here on stack-exchange.  Normally you could use "expect", but to be honest its really not worth the trouble to code yourself. I'll edit my answer a bit, with a recommendation.

Comment: @anishsane - No. You wont have that problem. That would be true if you omitted -I (for the first example) or -n (for the second & third).